# Node.js || How to write a file, then read it once it finishes writing?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am fairly new to node.js and I'm still learning my way around coding in general.
The following things are what I'm trying to accomplish...

[*]Request data from api.

[*]Write the data into a new JSON file.

[*]Read the newly written file.

[*]Extract specific information.

This is what I have going for me so far

```
let     request = require('request'),
        fs = require('fs'),
        DATA = require('./DATA.json'),
        url = "https://dataThatIAmTryingToGet";


        request(url, (error, response, body)=> {
          if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            fs.writeFile("./DATA.json", (body))
          } else {
            console.log("Got an error: ", error, ", status code: ", response.statusCode)
          }
        });

        if (fs.existsSync("./DATA.json")){
            fs.readFile("./DATA.json", (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Whoopsiedaisy");
                } else {
                    console.log("You did it nerd");
                    console.log(DATA.response.items.length);
                }
            })
        };
```

With this code I accomplish the first two off my checklist...

[X]Request data from api.

[X]Write the data into a new JSON file.

[*]Read the newly written file.

[*]Extract specific information.

The console is printing `You did it nerd`, but the error I am getting is that `console.log(DATA.response.items.length);` is returning `undefined` in the console.  Im trying to see how many specific items fall under `items` in the api. (Example of the api below).  My issue is that I'm not sure if it's because the file is being read too fast, or if I'm trying to read the data incorrectly.

Here is an example of the api output...

```
{
    "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "current_time": 1488743993,
        "raw_usd_value": 0.1,
        "usd_currency": "coins",
        "usd_currency_index": 5002,
        "items": {
            "Item 1": {
                "defindex": [
                    5002
                ],
                "prices": {
                    "6": {
                        "Tradable": {
                            "Craftable": [
                                {
                                    "value": 0.08,
                                    "currency": "usd",
                                    "difference": 0,
                                    "last_update": 1488385886,
                                    "value_high": 0.12
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "Item 2": {
                "defindex": [
                    5021
                ],
                "prices": {
                    "6": {
                        "Tradable": {
                            "Craftable": [
                                {
                                    "value": 14,
                                    "currency": "usd",
                                    "difference": 14.11,
                                    "last_update": 1488385975,
                                    "value_high": 14.22
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read the file inside the request callback, which isn't synchronous. Otherwise you're reading the file before you've written it.

Comment: I don't understand what that means.  Could you explain further?

Comment: Put another console.log on the line after you write to the file, and you'll see when that happens.

Comment: Does this mean that the console.log after the file is written wont run until the file is completely written?

Comment: No, because you aren't using writeFileSync. Indeed you're being inconsistent with the use of sync and async fs methods, which can't be helping with your confusion. Read up on async generally and callbacks specifically.

Comment: Thank you.  I will do that in the morning.  Its 1:30 am and I dont think any information will be retained if I try to learn about it right now.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a promise's to do such tasks. This will make the order of tasks very clear, and you get easily readable code without many nested callbacks. In below example I'm using [**bluebird**](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) for the promises, but you can implement the "promisification" for yourself if you insist. Below will do what you want (checking for `fs.existsSync` is not needed, should the file not exist it will simply throw an error in `fs.readFile` which you can handle in `catch`.

Little sidenote: `response.items.length` returns undefined because `items` is an object in your case, which doesn't have a `length` property. I suppose you've mixed that with an array.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const request = Promise.promisifyAll(require('request'));
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
const url = 'http://localhost:3000';

request.getAsync(url)
  .then(data => fs.writeFileAsync("output.json", data.body))
  .then(() => fs.readFileAsync("output.json", "UTF-8"))
  .then(data => console.log(JSON.parse(data).response))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Here's a simple mock server that just returns the data you posted:

```
/* MOCK SERVER */
const http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  res.end(JSON.stringify({
      "response": {
        "success": 1,
        "current_time": 1488743993,
        "raw_usd_value": 0.1,
        "usd_currency": "coins",
        "usd_currency_index": 5002,
        "items": {
          "Item 1": {
            "defindex": [
              5002
            ],
            "prices": {
              "6": {
                "Tradable": {
                  "Craftable": [
                    {
                      "value": 0.08,
                      "currency": "usd",
                      "difference": 0,
                      "last_update": 1488385886,
                      "value_high": 0.12
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "Item 2": {
            "defindex": [
              5021
            ],
            "prices": {
              "6": {
                "Tradable": {
                  "Craftable": [
                    {
                      "value": 14,
                      "currency": "usd",
                      "difference": 14.11,
                      "last_update": 1488385975,
                      "value_high": 14.22
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    })
  );
}).listen(3000);

/* END MOCK */
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the file **asynchronously**. This means that it will call `fs.writeFile` but then continue without waiting for it to finish. Because writing to the file system takes a [very small] amount of time, the program goes and calls the rest of the code while `fs.writeFile` is still going.

To fix this, simply put the rest of your code in the callback of `fs.writeFile`.

Hope that makes sense. See the fixed code below:

```
let request = require('request'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  DATA = require('./DATA.json'),
  url = "https://dataThatIAmTryingToGet";


request(url, (error, response, body) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    fs.writeFile("./DATA.json", (body), function () {
      if (fs.existsSync("./DATA.json")) {
        fs.readFile("./DATA.json", (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Whoopsiedaisy");
          } else {
            console.log("You did it nerd");
            console.log(DATA.response.items.length);
          }
        })
      }
    })
  } else {
    console.log("Got an error: ", error, ", status code: ", response.statusCode)
  }
});
```

Comment: It is still returning Undefined

Comment: @Ryder Sorry, try now though. I added something that I didn't pick up on at first.

Comment: _You need to call this function **synchronously**_ That's not a good idea

Comment: @baao Why not? The nature of this code is that you want to wait for stuff to finish before continuing

Comment: No, you continue in the callback

Comment: @baao is there an advantage of doing it that way? I thought they both achieve the same end result

Comment: Yeah, you're not blocking everything